# Why does the recommended dispose pattern adds a disposed field at each level of the hierarchy?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, idisposable

The `Dispose` pattern is notoriously complicated to get right, especially when we have a hierarchy of classes that needs to dispose things at different levels. The recommended implementation is as follow, took from [Implement a Dispose method - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose#implement-the-dispose-pattern).

```cs
using System;

class BaseClass : IDisposable
{
    // To detect redundant calls
    private bool _disposed = false;

    ~BaseClass() => Dispose(false);

    // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
            // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
        }

        // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
        // TODO: set large fields to null.

        _disposed = true;
    }
}

using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // To detect redundant calls
    private bool _disposed = false;

    // Instantiate a SafeHandle instance.
    private SafeHandle _safeHandle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
           // Dispose managed state (managed objects).
            _safeHandle?.Dispose();
        }

        _disposed = true;

        // Call base class implementation.
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

What I don't get in this implementation is what advantage we have in adding a `_disposed` field at each level of the hierarchy? Instead, we could take care of the `_disposed` only in the top level of the hierarchy (the one implementing directly `IDisposable` and not care about it in the derived classes.

Something like this:

```cs
using System;

class BaseClass : IDisposable
{
    // To detect redundant calls
    private bool _disposed = false;

    ~BaseClass()
    {
       if (_disposed)
       {
          return;
       }

       Dispose(false);
       _disposed = true;
    }

    // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        _disposed = true;
    }

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
        }

        // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
        // TODO: set large fields to null.
    }
}

using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // Instantiate a SafeHandle instance.
    private SafeHandle _safeHandle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
           // Dispose managed state (managed objects).
            _safeHandle?.Dispose();
        }

        // Call base class implementation.
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

This is such a widely used code sample that there must certainly be a good reason for it to be implemented with the repeated `_disposed` at each level, but I just can't find any.

It's a tiny bit more code in the base class, but less to worry about in the derived class, and some repeated information removed.

What else am I missing?

Edit:

As @InBetween correctly says that one drawback of my implementation is that if you'd need to check if your object is disposed in one method of the derived class you won't be able to check it. Let's correct that issue by making it a protected property with a private set.

```cs
using System;

class BaseClass : IDisposable
{
    // To detect redundant calls
    protected bool Disposed { get; private set; } = false;

    ~BaseClass()
    {
       if (Disposed)
       {
          return;
       }

       Dispose(false);
       Disposed = true;
    }

    // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        Disposed = true;
    }

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
        }

        // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
        // TODO: set large fields to null.
    }
}

using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // Instantiate a SafeHandle instance.
    private SafeHandle _safeHandle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);

    public void DoSomething()
    {
       if(Disposed)
       {
           throw new ObjectDisposedException("Cannot access disposed resource");
       }
    }    

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
           // Dispose managed state (managed objects).
            _safeHandle?.Dispose();
        }

        // Call base class implementation.
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of where `_disposed` is implemented at each level? The code you've provide doesn't show that unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The first code, the one took from MSDN, you can see that there is a `private _disposed` field in `BaseClass` and in `DerivedClass` which means it would be implemented at each level, because it's the virtual `Dispose` method that checks / sets it.

Comment: @Enigmativity what browser are you using? You might not be seeing the scroll bar in the code and see only the first Base class. It's a "long" code so SO adds a scroll bar in the code.

Comment: The guideline says about the pattern (not implementation), what is enough to provide to make a disposable class valid in context of inheritance in any potential case, but it doesn't bind you to a specific implementation of the pattern. I mean either your `Dispose` method check/change a `protected` property or a `private` field it's up to you, you know your specific use case and you will decide how to implement it properly. What the guideline really makes you do (in fact it's in the bullet list in the beginning of the section) doesn't have a word about `private` field.

Comment: Moreover, the guideline can also show the case when you don't have an access to a `base` type, so that you have to specify your own `_disposing` flag. And implementer of the `base` type could just follow the guideline and decided that he/she didn't want to provide any `protected` properties for some reasons, but they followed the pattern and you still can use their class properly. See what I mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is simple. In your implementation you cant use `_disposed` in the derived type to check if any method is invoked when the object is already disposed and take the necessary actions. In your implementation you'd need to create your own redundant flag `isDisposed` which defeats the purpose; you already have one "for free" from the pattern itself following the guidelines.

A case could be made though about making `_disposed` `protected`.

Comment: hmm i've always seen it private though - would there be no implications by sharing it between all overloads?

Comment: You could make the `Disposed` property with the `get` protected and private `set` if you'd need to check

Comment: Edited my question with the example using the property, it still looks better to me than the MSDN sample, except if I'm missing something else.

Comment: @Gimly I'm not sure why you are bent on changing the implementation. If you make `_disposed` a protected member/field in the base class you don't need to change anything in the guideline's implementation except removing the redundant `_disposed = true` inside the overrides of `Dispose(disposing`).

Comment: @gimly Why does the guideline implementation not consider `disposing` as a protected member/field? Right now I can't think of a reason of how this could become an issue so its probably about keeping it simple; `_disposing` is not really necessary for a correct implementation of the pattern, there are many otherways where you can make `Dispose` idempotent and maybe the base class chose a different one. Or maybe initially it did use a `_disposed` flag but then in a new version it doesn't and now it has to carry an unecessary burden of keeping the flag updates for consumers when its not needed.

Comment: @Gimly To make a long story short; having private field on each hierarchy level is an insignifcant cost. Having a single common flag throughout the whole hierarchy on the other hand can, on some ocassions, be unecessay or even redundant and it doesn't really add any value at all.

Answer (score 4):

If you are inheriting from a disposable class, one of two conditions must be true.

1. Your subcless does not introduce a new disposable resource. In this case you don't need to override `Dispose` and the question is moot.
2. Your subclass introduces a new disposable resource. In this case, you're going to override `Dispose`, insert your own disposal code, then call `base.Dispose`. The `_disposed` flag is there to help you remember to prevent your disposal code from executing twice.

You certainly can remove `_disposed` if you want. But you probably do not care much about the base class' `_disposed` flag, if it even has one. It worries about what it is disposing, and you worry about yours.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think that answers the question. I'm not asking why there is a `_disposed` flag, I'm asking why this `_disposed` flag is repeated (`private _disposed`) at each level of the hierarchy and not just took care by the base class. See my edited code where I used a protected property to manage this flag.